# What does "WPA" mean in ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"

Tags: freebsd, wifi

The handbook suggests that these settings can be used for [WPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) in FreeBSD:

```
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
```

But as far as I'm concerned this very settings can be used for [WEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy).
So what does "WPA" here stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code inside `/etc/network.subr`, "WPA" is a pseudo argument which triggers invocation of `wpa_supplicant`.

Answer (score 0):

WPA indicate that the wireless device wlan0 use WPA security protocols.

For WEP:

```
wepmode on
```